# QGIS ValueMap - fill value AND description into parent layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-form

i have a layer with trees (points) and a CSV as value map with tree types. In the tree layer as well in th CSV i have a column with the latin tree name and another one with the german name (tree_latin; tree_ger). If a fieldworker selects in the attribute form a latin name, the matching value for the german name should be automatically set as well(and vice versa).

As there are 200~ tree types specified in the CSV, i can not work with a default value and "CASE WHEN TREETYPE_LATIN_XYZ THEN TREETYPE_GER_XYZ"

Any ideas how to achive that?

Comment: To my knowledge it is not possible to base an automatically filled in attribute upon another attribute which is being filled in during the creation of the same feature.